# Gfortran attribute that requires an explicit interface for this procedure

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran95

I am new to Fortran, trying to compile a Atmospheric Wind model which is available here:
http://nssdcftp.gsfc.nasa.gov/models/atmospheric/hwm07/

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and gfortan (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)).

The model contains 4 datafiles with .f90 extension and 3 of them compile just fine. The last one gives me the error:

```
$ gfortran -c hwm07e.f90 
hwm07e.f90:168.22:

        call HWMupdate(input,last,gfs,gfl,gfm,gvbar,gwbar,gbz,gbm,gzwght,glev,u
                  1
Error: Dummy argument 'ebz' of procedure 'hwmupdate' at (1) has an attribute that             requires an explicit interface for this procedure
hwm07e.f90:168.22:

        call HWMupdate(input,last,gfs,gfl,gfm,gvbar,gwbar,gbz,gbm,gzwght,glev,u
                  1
Error: Dummy argument 'ebz' of procedure 'hwmupdate' at (1) has an attribute that requires an explicit interface for this procedure
```

`ebz` and `ebm` are defined as targets which seems to be a source of the problem:

```
subroutine HWMupdate(input,last,fs,fl,fm,vbar,wbar,ebz,ebm,zwght,lev,u,v)
use NewModel
implicit none

...

real(8),intent(inout),target    :: ebz(nbf,0:p)
real(8),intent(inout),target    :: ebm(nbf,0:p)

...

ebz = 0.0
ebm = 0.0

    bz => ebz(:,b)
    bm => ebm(:,b)
```

In the included makefile.g95 it suggests to use g95 as the compiler, is it possible that it is not possible to compile this using gfortran?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is (and you are) correct here that the call to `HWMupdate` requires an explicit interface because of the `target` attribute on the dummy arguments.  This doesn't mean that a compiler must reject the code: `ifort` for example can be persuaded to continue, and perhaps `g95` also.

To get your compilation to continue, you could find a compiler flag to allow this: `-fno-whole-file` being possibly one option as this restricts `gfortran`'s ability to do this checking.  The documentation recommends against doing this, however.

If you aren't against changing the code then a better solution would be to [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16881363/3157076) an explicit interface.